# Facebook Status Update from Android Game

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to build a feature in my android game where users can post their scores on FB. I have completed the required integration steps but when I try to post to FB I get the following error:

An Error Occurred. Please try later

There is no error message, so I am not sure if this is an app authentication issue with FB or some error with my code.

Please let me know if I need to get the app approved by FB to get this functionality running in the test environment. The "Status and Review page at FB asks for a privacy policy URL but I do not have one for my app. Please let me know if a privacy policy URL is required for such integration.

Also, the following is my code. It would be great if anyone could let me know if I am missing something.

Following are the relevant tags in my manifest:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="BookQuotesQuiz" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider701127413351677"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

The following is my code for posting to FB:

public void updateFBStatus(View view) {

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    final ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result result) {
            Log.d("SUCCESS", "success");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("CANCEL", "cancel");
        }
    });
    if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
               .setContentTitle("Book Quotes Quiz: Highscore")
               .setContentDescription("My new highscore is " + score)
               .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.games.bookquotesquiz"))
               .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://lh3.ggpht.com/v7Q3EB6HvvBW9mC4WPokSZC6QM1hFFk5Gp5Nj97nLtwYkXQXe4jLmJUa8OSwYfssz6c=w300-rw"))
               .build();
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `onActivityResult` on your Activity:

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```